# SAXParseException, failed to read schema document web-app_3_0.xsd

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on a project migration from old java web project :

- java 1.5 to 1.8
- tomcat 5 to tomcat 7
- eclipse 3 to 2021-09
  The project is pretty simple (no maven, servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar).
  The project is starting but when I'm calling a page I have a validation error :

```
GRAVE: PUBLIC ID invalide: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
mai 05, 2023 10:11:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
org.xml.sax.SAXException: schema error: error reading schema document: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:218)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.processWebDotXml(JspConfig.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.init(JspConfig.java:231)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.findJspProperty(JspConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.casino.pdc.servlet.Demarrage.jspAppeler(Demarrage.java:64)
    at com.casino.pdc.servlet.Demarrage.tacheTraiter(Demarrage.java:83)
    at com.casino.fwk.tools.HttpServletGenerique.doPost(HttpServletGenerique.java:245)
    at com.casino.fwk.tools.HttpServletGenerique.doGet(HttpServletGenerique.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can't figure out why the validation is based on web-app_3_0.xsd but in my web.xml, I put :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

I tried to change the web.xml web-app tag and put "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" as schema but it changed nothing.